# Stackexchange.Redis foreach 10000 times get return 1 or 2 times 'null'

Tags: stackexchange.redis

```
ICacheProvider cache = CacheFactory.CreateCacheProvider("FrameworkTest.Redis");
var k = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    var j = cache.Get<String>("lobi");

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(j))
    {
        k++;
        Console.Write("???");
    }
}
Console.Write(k);
```

The param 'j' will be null one or two times.

Sorry,My English is bad.

Comment: conn = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(options);
 conn.PreserveAsyncOrder = false;

Comment: var value = redisClient.StringGetAsync(key);
                return SerializeUtil.Deserialize<T>(redisClient.Wait(value));